# Arabic and Latin characters are rendered wrong on iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, rtl

[image]

The 1 from “1 hour ago” should not render in the middle of his name.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 11.0 (Build 15A5341f) (Beta 5)